# Transformations an array, combination of between map and reduce

Tags: functional-programming, swift, swift3

I'm working on a function that reduces pairs of elements if they meet some criteria.

For example, given an array: `["1", "2", "a", "b", "3", "4"]` I want to transform it so that strings that represent numbers are combined with addition, and strings that represent letters are concatenated so the output would be: `["3" "ab" "7"]`.

The approach I've taken is to sort of gobble the array up from the head pair, which with the example above goes through the following steps:

```
(1, 2, a, b, 3, 4) // combine 1 and 2 ->
(3, a, b, 3, 4) // combine a and b ->
(3, ab, 3, 4) // combine 3 and 4 ->
(3, ab, 7)
```

I'm calling transform a 'knot' because I'm visualizing elements in the array being knotted together to unlimitedly shorten the sequence.

Is this a pattern that's known by some other name? Any suggestions other than knot that might be more descriptive (knit? squish?).

Here's the current approach in Swift, would be great to get any feedback on style, documentation, or algorithm here:

```
public extension Array {

    /// A `knot` is like a discriminating `reduce`.
    ///
    /// Knotting an array incrementally looks at the next pair of sequential elements, and attempts to use 
    /// a closure to reduce that pair of elements into a single element.
    ///
    /// Unlike `reduce` this closure can be failable, in which case the element is not reduced, but simply 
    /// appended to the results.
    ///
    ///   - Note: Forward knots.
    ///   If (A  B  C D) can be knotted successfully as (ABCD) through series of knots:
    ///   (A B C D) -> (AB C D) -> (ABC D) -> (ABCD).
    ///
    ///   It's possible that A and B **cannot** be knotted, but A and BC **can** be knotted to achieve the
    ///   equivalent result:
    ///   (A B C D) -> (A BC D) -> (ABC D) -> ABCD
    ///
    /// - Parameter forwardKnot: A flag to indicate if a forward-knot should be attempted if the initial knot 
    ///   fails.
    ///
    /// - Parameter transform: A knotting closure. `transform` accepts a pair of elements from this sequence
    ///   as its parameter and returns a transformed value of the same type if the pair should be combined, or
    ///   nil if the element can't be combined.
    ///
    /// - Returns: An array containing the transformed elements of this sequence.
    func knot(forwards forwardKnot: Bool = false, 
              _ transform: ((Element, Element) -> Element?)) -> [Element] {

        var upcoming = self

        var knotted: [Element] = []
        knotted.reserveCapacity(count)

        while !upcoming.isEmpty {

            let next = upcoming.remove(at: 0)

            // first iteration - nothing to knot, just add next element
            guard let last = knotted.last else {
                knotted.append(next)
                continue
            }

            // attempt to knot
            if let knot = transform(last, next) {
                knotted[knotted.count-1] = knot
            }
            else {
                if forwardKnot, let ahead = upcoming.first, 
                    let under = transform(next, ahead), 
                    let over = transform(last, under) {

                    upcoming.remove(at: 0)
                    knotted[knotted.count-1] = over
                }
                // can't forward knot, just add the next element
                else {
                    knotted.append(next)
                }
            }
        }

        return knotted
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
func additiveKnot(left: String, right: String) -> String? {

    let left: Any = Int(left) ?? left
    let right: Any = Int(right) ?? right

    switch (left, right) {

    case let(left as String, right as String):
        // knot Strings by concatenating
        // "a", "b" => "ab"
        return left + right

    case let (left as Int, right as Int):
        // knot Ints by addition
        // 1, 2 => 3
        return String(left + right)

    default:
        return nil
    }
}

let values = ["1", "2", "a", "b", "3", "4"]
let knotted = values.knot(additiveKnot)
// 'knotted' == ["3", "ab", "7"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks overall good to me and is correct, as far as I can see.
Possible improvements:

- `upcoming` is a copy of the given array from which one or two elements are 
  removed at the front in each iteration step. Removing the first element of an
  array moves all remaining elements to the front and is a O(N) operation.
  This can be improved by using an *array slice* instead:

  ```
  var upcoming = ArraySlice(self)
  ```

  Removing the first element of an array slice only  adjusts the start index
  and is an O(1) operation.

  Then

  ```
   while !upcoming.isEmpty {
      let next = upcoming.remove(at: 0)
      ...
  }
  ```

  can be simplified to

  ```
   while let next = upcoming.popFirst() {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Append to the `knotted` array only "finalized" values which can not be combined with
  upcoming values anymore, and use a separate variable for the current value
  which is still a candidate for further combination. This allows to move the

  ```
      // first iteration - nothing to knot, just add next element
  ```

  check outside of the loop.
- Use `elsif` instead of a nested `else { if .. }` statement.
- Perhaps there is a reason for naming the variables `over` and `under` in the
  forward knot part, but I did not get that.

The method would then look like this:

```
func knot(forwards forwardKnot: Bool = false,
           _ transform: ((Element, Element) -> Element?)) -> [Element] {

    var upcoming = ArraySlice(self)
    // Set `current` to first element:
    guard var current = upcoming.popFirst() else { return [] }

    var knotted: [Element] = []
    knotted.reserveCapacity(count)

    // Iterate over all remaining elements:
    while let next = upcoming.popFirst() {
        if let knot = transform(current, next) {
            // Successful knot, update `current`.
            current = knot
        } else if forwardKnot,
            let ahead = upcoming.first,
            let nextTwo = transform(next, ahead),
            let knot = transform(current, nextTwo) {

            // Successful forward knot, update `current`.  
            current = knot
            upcoming.removeFirst()
        } else {
            // No knot. Append `current` to final array and make `next` the 
            // next candidate.
            knotted.append(current)
            current = next
        }
    }

    knotted.append(current)
    return knotted
}
```

Without the "forward knot" feature you could iterate over the array elements
directly:

```
func knot(_ transform: ((Element, Element) -> Element?)) -> [Element] {

    guard var current = self.first else { return [] }

    var knotted: [Element] = []
    for elem in self.dropFirst() {
        if let knot = transform(current, elem) {
            current = knot
        } else {
            knotted.append(current)
            current = elem
        }
    }
    knotted.append(current)
    return knotted
}
```

---

The `additiveKnot()` function can be simplified, your code does

```
  String -> Any -> String
  String -> Int -> Any -> Int
```

conversions. You can do a pattern matching on `Int(left)` and `Int(right)`
instead, this avoids all unnecessary type conversions and does not require
`Any` at all.

The `switch` statement  checks if `Int(left)` and `Int(right)`
are both `!= nil` (two integers), both `== nil` (two strings), or if the
values are of "mixed type":

```
func additiveKnot(left: String, right: String) -> String? {

    switch (Int(left), Int(right)) {
    case let (leftInt?, rightInt?): // Both are integers
        return String(leftInt + rightInt)
    case (nil, nil): // None of them is an integer
        return left + right
    default: // Mixed case
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here `leftInt?` is a shortcut for the `.some(leftInt)` pattern.

Comment: Thank you! I really like all these changes, especially the `current` variable so that only finalized knots are added to the array. I need to spend more time with docs learning where there are O(1) opportunities. 

You're right about the `over`/`under` variable names. They're leftovers from when I was thinking about option to define a different closures for a 'forward knot'.

Thanks again for taking time to write this, I’ve learnt a lot!

Comment: @MathewS: You are welcome!